# PHP stores variables in cache

Tags: php, html, mysql, caching, header

I got this problem with my site, where I got some values from a database, I show it in a table on a page, and from that page, you can change the values. But when I change the values, run the MySQL query that updates the fields, and use

```
    header("Location: contact.php")
```

to go back to the page thats shows the values. But the values do not change to the new ones, before I press Ctrl+F5. Is there any way to prevent the site from storing the data, and showing fresh ones right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple just add a random `GET` request in the `header` method as follows:

`header("Location: contact.php?dummy=")`

will work fine, You can also pass random values to `dummy=<some random value>` using random method for better performance...

Comment: Why would that work?
And i am already passing a get with an id, the the php knows what info to get from the Database

Comment: The caching is specifically done by client browser (ifcourse you can manually disable it.). Thus when you redirect your script to the same url (i.e. itself) browser intends to display cached results to save time. But when you specify a `GET` it now expects updated results, thus, completely displays fresh value responded by the server.

Comment: But as said, the link to the site is: /contact.php?id=1
But it still wont update automaticly

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that... But isin't the link same before as well as after the update???? (i.e. `id=1` stays the same for that user) Whenever the browser finds the same url to load as the current one it displays cached results Thats why I said to include random values to a `dummy` variable which makes the url 'LOOK' different in the browser's part every time you reload. Thus avoiding chances of cached results. If you have an `id=1` then the url would be as: `$url="/contact.php?id=1&dummy=".rand(); header("Location: $url");`

Comment: Thank you, that helped alot! Just missed the part, where the $_GET had to be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you're encountering a caching issue, as @Anirban mentioned. However, if you don't actually want the results cached, it's probably better to prevent the caching in the first place, rather than to have the browser store a bunch of data it's not going to use. You can add these headers:

```
header('Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')
header('Pragma:no-cache')
header('Expires:0')
```

in your PHP code at the top of the `contact.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have tried. I tried every possible Meta tag suggested with cache-problems, but none of them work.